# How to access a specific value in a text file using C++

Tags: c++, stream, console, token, fstream

my text file has this structure and this values

```
15.32 15.00 14.58 14.36 17.85 01.95 15.36 
14.58 21.63 25.00 47.11 48.95 45.63 12.00
74.58 52.66 45.55 47.65 15.55 00.23 78.69
```

each column is a different type of data, the first column is weigh , second is  size and so on.
the user requests for instance the weight, which would be the first column

```
15.32
14.58
74.58
```

and i need to print

```
reg 1 reg 2 reg 3
15.32 14.58 74.58
```

also, the user can request other column i don't know how i can accomplish this
i am able only to print the first line

```
15.32 15.00 14.58 14.36 17.85 01.95 15.36
```

using this code, but only if i use integer files, if they are double the below code does nothing

```
string nextToken;
while (myfile>> nextToken) {
    cout << "Token: " << nextToken << endl;
}
```

but i don't know how to move between columns and lines

I am using this structure

```
struct measures{
    string date;
    double weight;
    double size;
    double fat;
    double imc;
    double chest;
    double waist;
} dataclient;
```

i read the values like this

```
ofstream file;
file.open (dataclient.id, ios::out | ios::app);
if (file.is_open())
{
    cout<<"   ENTER THE WEIGH"<<endl;
    cin>>dataclient.weigh;
    file<<dataclient.weigh<<" ";

    cout<<"   ENTER THE SIZE"<<endl;
    cin>>dataclient.size;
    file<<dataclient.size<<" ";

    cout<<"  ENTER  % FAT"<<endl;
    cin>>dataclient.fat;
    file<<dataclient.fat<<" ";
```

this can be done several times for an user,and then closes the file

after that, the user request any of the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An even easier way is to make a function with two parameters: the starting item and the "stride", or the number of items per row. You can then skip items until the starting item and then skip the stride between successive items:

```
void printcolumn(int start, int stride, ifstream &in)
{
  string nextToken;

  // skip until the start
  while(start-->0) in >> nextToken;

  // and then start writing the items
  while (in >> nextToken) 
  {
    cout << "Token: " << nextToken << endl;

    // and skip the stride
    for(int i=1;i<stride;++i) in >> nextToken;
  }
}
```

For your specific example, you'd call it like `printcolumn(0, 7, myfile);`

Comment: this worked like a charm , thanks a lot, I couldn't resolve this without all your help.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do things like this is create a structure or class to encapsulate the data that appears in a "record." (A record being a row)  Read each row into a new instance of that class and then just pull the data from the appropriate members variables that you need.

EDIT: Also, I would like to add that this answer gave me some 1337 rep :)

Comment: struct measures{       
string date;
double weight;
double size;
double fat;
double imc;
double chest;
double waist;

} medclient;

Comment: @user59594 Yes, exactly!  After you've read all your data into those members, it's just a matter of reading the variables!

Answer (score 0):

This code loads in the entire file of `measure`s into a vector called `data` and remembers all of it.  Then when a user wants to access a particular `measure`, you can simply read it from `data`.

```
// This demo will only handle three records.
// if you want to work with more records, change this number
const unsigned int numRecords = 3;
// This defines a structure called measures, as you detailed
// I don't create a measure object, I simply tell the computer what it is.
struct measures{ 
    string date; 
    double weight; 
    double size; 
    double fat; 
    double imc; 
    double chest; 
    double waist; 
};
// This is complicated
// Basically, it makes it really easy to load a measure from a stream.
//   like a file stream or std::cin.
// I refer to this as "operator>>"
istream& operator>>(istream& i, measures& m) {
    // The function takes a stream and a measure
    //   and reads each member from the stream one by one into the measure 
    i >> m.date;
    i >> m.weight;
    i >> m.size;
    i >> m.fat;
    i >> m.imc;
    i >> m.chest;
    i >> m.waist;
    // The "operator>>()" function must always return the stream
    return i;
}

int main() {
  // A vector is a container, that holds objects
  // A vector<measures> is a container that contains measure objects.
  // I make a vector<measures> named "data".
  // I use the constructor that takes the size of the vector.
  // We want 3 measures, so I give it the number recNum(3).
  // This makes a container of recNum(3) measures.
  vector<measures> data(numRecords );
  // I assume you already know how to open a file
  std::ifstream myfile("myfile.txt");
  // Now we want to go through the file and load measures
  // recNum will be the line we're at
  // we go from 0 to numRecords(3), one at a time
  for(int recNum=0; recNum<numRecords; recNum += 1) {
      // First we get the measure to be loaded from the container
      // Since the container "owns" the object, I have to get the
      //   object by reference.  That's the "&" symbol.
      // It means I'm changing it, but I don't own it.
      // It belongs to the container.
      // We use the [recNum] to tell it which measure we want
      measures& newMeasure = data[recNum];
      // Now that we have the Measure that needs to be loaded,
      //   we call the special "operator>>" function that I wrote above
      // Yeah.   It's like magic or something.          
      myfile >> data[recNum];
  }
  // Done loading the measures into the container
  // The container now contains numRecords(3) measures.

  // Figure out the record that the user wants here.
  //   and put it in recordNum. (Remember that 0 is the first item,
  //   so 1 is the second item)
  int recordNum = 1; 

  // Again, we get the measure to be loaded from the container
  // We use the [recNum] to tell it which measure we want
  // Since the container "owns" the object, We have to get the
  //   object by reference again.  We don't "own" the object
  measures& userMeasure = data[recordNum];
  // We can access the weight of this measure with userMeasure.weight
  cout << "Record number " <<  recordNum;
  cout << " has a weight of: " << userMeasure .weight << ".\n";
}
```

Comment: my C++ knowledge is almost nothing.I am beginner.

Comment: Your code is fine (in my opinion) except for one thing, you have to know the numbers of records. Why not read each record into a temporary variable which you push_back to the vector (`while (myfile >> tmp) data.push_back(tmp);`) ?

Comment: @Christian Ammer: One step at a time.  I thought about that, but decided against it.

Comment: @user59594: I added TONS of comments to the code, that explains everything but how to open the file.  (You can obviously already do that)

Comment: Sorry for being curious, but why do you decide against it? It has no drawback doing so, but if set your vector containing exactly 3 elements, then you have no clue that e.g. the program had read only 2 records.

Comment: Static sizes do have the limitations you mention, but are a far simpler concept.  As the OP is a beginner, I figured I'd stick to simpler concepts.  I did suggest a vector rather than an array, so as he learns this code can be easily upgraded to do as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this thread [MSDN Forum, Visual C++ General](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/9a03faf2-78a0-4581-9a03-6dac45529522/#9a03faf2-78a0-4581-9a03-6dac45529522) 
There is a solution for a file with two columns, but it can be any number of columns.
You read text in std::string then write it in std::vector and then work with its elements.